# Install HTTP/2.0 using directadmin with letsencrypt on centos 7 server

Tags: centos7, http2, directadmin

I want to install and activate HTTP.2 on my server.Centos 7
I follow this article
[How to Activate HTTP/2 Support on DirectAdmin (CentOS)](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-activate-http2-support-on-directadmin-centos/)
But to the last step [Step 3: Enable HTTP/2 in Apache]
(./build apache)
but an error message appears
(PHP mode 'mod_php' is not supported, please set php1_release=php-fpm|fastcgi|lsphp in CustomBuild 'options.conf'.)

I tried to modify the [options.conf] file set
(php1_release=php-fpm|fastcgi|lsphp)
but the same error message still appeared.
So I would like to ask how to solve this problem
Thanks